# Integer out of range (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, python-3.6, biginteger

Вообщем, у меня есть персонаж в бд у которого есть атрибут баланса:

```
balance = peewee.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

Но игроки бывают доходят до большого баланса и peewee выдает ошибку (Integer out of range)
Насколько я знаю у bigint максимальное число (9223372036854775807)

Как мне обойти это ограничение и что использовать? Мне нужно что бы баланс был впредь до 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываем мануал в разделе [числовых типов данных](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) и ищем другой, более подходящий тип данных:

Вам подойдёт `numeric` (`decimal` аналогичен), способный хранить до 131072 знаков перед запятой.